# How to code in a select tag having different view content

Tags: html

I'm creating a website for my team at work in HTML, where a part of it, they need to select the person they are sending an email to within the site, and so I'm wanting the

I have the select tags as well as the option tags, and the selector works, but I don't know who to get the different options to show different things outside of the select option

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<title> ITAccess  Emails</title>
</head>
<p><h3>Qliksense Complete</h3></p>
<p>Hi <select>
  <option value="Martin">Martin</option>
  <option value="David">David</option>
  <option value="Jen">Jen</option>
  <option value="Latheesh ">Latheesh</option>
  <option value="Bex ">Bex</option>
  <option value="Ralph ">Ralph</option>
  <option value="Craig">Craig</option>
</select>, <br>
<br>
I hope you are well. <br>
<br>
The request you raised for <strong>User/s name/s </strong> to have Qliksense Access is now complete. Please note, it will take up to 2 hours for the group to a make full effect on the user/s account.<br>
<br>
Bicc-<em>Jira reference NO</em></P>
<a href="mailto:name1@mail.com,name2@mail.com?subject=Ticket%20Ref%20-%20Qliksense%20Access-%20Complete&amp;body=Hi%20Requestor%2C%20%0A%0AI%20hope%20you%20are%20well.%20%0A%0AThe%20request%20you%20raised%20for%20User%2Fs%20name%2Fs%20to%20have%20Qliksense%20Access%20is%20now%20complete.%20Please%20note%2C%20it%20will%20take%20up%20to%202%20hours%20for%20the%20group%20to%20make%20a%20full%20effect%20on%20the%20user%2Fs%20account.%0A%0ABicc-Jira%20reference%20NO">QlikSense Complete</a>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the names are, the user can select which person they are sending the email to before clicking on the mailto link, and I'm wanting the Mailto link to change appropriately depend ing on the name selected ie if martin was selected, to email him etc.

FYI: I DO NOT need the mailto links doing.

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to use javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code has the `<body>` tag before `<head>` which is formerly wrong. Move `<body>` after `</head>`.
Then, as other users said, you need JavaScript to achieve your goal:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> ITAccess  Emails</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><h3>Qliksense Complete</h3></p>
<p>Hi <select onchange="updateHref(this.value)">
  <option value="martin@domain.ext">Martin</option>
  <option value="david@domain.ext">David</option>
  <option value="jen@domain.ext">Jen</option>
  <option value="latheesh@domain.ext">Latheesh</option>
  <option value="bex@domain.ext">Bex</option>
  <option value="ralph@domain.ext">Ralph</option>
  <option value="craig@domain.ext">Craig</option>
</select>, <br>
<br>
I hope you are well. <br>
<br>
The request you raised for <strong>User/s name/s </strong> to have Qliksense Access is now complete. Please note, it will take up to 2 hours for the group to a make full effect on the user/s account.<br>
<br>
Bicc-<em>Jira reference NO</em></P>
<a id="mailto_link" href="mailto:name1@mail.com,name2@mail.com?subject=Ticket%20Ref%20-%20Qliksense%20Access-%20Complete&amp;body=Hi%20Requestor%2C%20%0A%0AI%20hope%20you%20are%20well.%20%0A%0AThe%20request%20you%20raised%20for%20User%2Fs%20name%2Fs%20to%20have%20Qliksense%20Access%20is%20now%20complete.%20Please%20note%2C%20it%20will%20take%20up%20to%202%20hours%20for%20the%20group%20to%20make%20a%20full%20effect%20on%20the%20user%2Fs%20account.%0A%0ABicc-Jira%20reference%20NO">QlikSense Complete</a>
<br>
<script>
function updateHref(val) {
    var oldHref = document.querySelector('#mailto_link').href;
    var newHref = oldHref.replace(/mailto:[^\?]+\?/, 'mailto:' + val + '?');
    document.querySelector('#mailto_link').href = newHref;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this contains a little bit of logic, you cannot achieve the desired functionality with just HTML which is just a markup language. Please use this [link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-the-value-of-selected-option-in-a-select-box-using-jquery.php) and see how you can employ Javascript to get what you want with Jquery.